# PostgreSQL Cursor does't exist

Tags: postgresql, cursor

i am new to postgresql and learning the use of cursor in procudure.

i have declared a cursor and while looping on cursor only one row is getting updated and then cursor ids doesn't exist error is thrown.

from tableA 5 rows is fetching and i have to update all the matching 5 records in tableB.

Below is the procedure

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST
Language plpgsql
as $procedure$

Declare 

id record;
c_ids cursor for select transaction_id from tableA where id = 1;

Begin 

  open c_ids;
   loop
    fetch c_ids into id;
    exit when not found;
    update tableB set column1 = 'XXX' where transaction_id = id;
   end loop;
  close ids;

 End;
 $procedure$
```

Comment: See [Cursor Loop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html#PLPGSQL-CURSOR-FOR-LOOP)

Comment: Why use a slow and inefficient loop at all?  This can be done with a single UPDATE statement. No loop or PL/pgSQL required

Comment: @AdrianKlaver..Thanks i have now resolved the issue.

Comment: There are many bugs: 1) you have no parentheses after the procedure name 2) you close the non-existing cursor `ids` 3) you name a variable (`id`) like an unqualified table column, leading to ambiguity 4) you cannot compare a `record` with a number, you must fetch the appropriate element of the record.